# How do you hyphenate 'luminous' over 2 verse lines, 'lumi-nous' or 'lumin-ous'? Help

Tags: hyphenation

How do you hyphenate 'luminous' over two verse lines, 'lumi-nous' or 'lumin-ous'? Help.

Answer (score 3):

Some dictionaries give hyphenation points in their definitions. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luminous) is one such.

> lu·mi·nous

Comment: In addition to this sage advice, because it's verse, the versifier has the option of hyphenating any word wherever it will serve the verse's or author's purpose.

Comment: In fact, if it serves their purpose, the versifier even has the option of hyphenating it lumy-nous.

Comment: In general, punctuation in poetry is to used very, very, sparingly. Especially punctuation thats silent. as cummings and antin have pointed out repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

In poetry, the sound is even more important than anywhere else.

So the answer to your question depends on how you ***say*** it.
If you **must** hyphenate, for some reason, make the hyphenation represent the sound.

- If you end the line with /m/, hyphenate after M
- If you end the line with /n/, hyphenate after N
- In general, hyphenate after the last sound in the line.

I.e, never mind official punctuation rules.
This is poetry, and poetry does what it must.